# No overlapping data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

Being a new user of postgres, I have created a database in postgres 13. It contains tables
including 4 Fields

1. ID integer (PK)
2. HoleID varchar(20)
3. From numeric NOT NULL CHECK (From>=0)
4. To numeric
5. Cat varchar (20)

I want to create a constraint that will check that for an identical entity number, the From and To fields of a record must not overlap with another record.

I have proposed the exclude constraint below but it does not work

ADD CONSTRAINT no_overlap EXCLUDE USING GIST ("HoleID" WITH =, ("mFrom", "mTo") WITH &&);

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Consider using a single [`numrange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) instead of from/to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tab
ADD CONSTRAINT no_overlap EXCLUDE USING gist (
   "HoleID" WITH =,
   numrange("mFrom", "mTo") WITH &&
);
```

You should never store a timestamp as number.

Answer (score 1):

This is easier with a single `numrange` column instead of from/to.

```
create table thing (
  id bigserial primary key,
  holeid varchar(20),
  range numrange not null,
  exclude using gist (range with &&, holeid with =)
);

insert into thing (holeid, range) values
  ('foo', '[1, 10]'::numrange),
  -- ok, same holeid, does not overlap
  ('foo', '[10.1, 11]'::numrange),
  -- ok, different holeid, overlaps.
  ('bar', '[2,5]'::numrange),
  -- not ok, same holeid, overlaps.
  ('foo', '[0, 1]'::numrange);
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d7fd44bf9e007287c0c93f865e455104).

Note that `[]` is inclusive and `()` is exclusive. `(1,10)::numrange` and `(10,20)::numrange` do not overlap. `[1,10]::numrange` and `[10,20]::numrange` do overlap.

Comment: Ok, it's clear but my database should absolutely contains From and To fields.

Comment: So is it possible to create a generated numrange column which will use From and to field? If yes how

Comment: @Lamethode Consider whether you really need those colums, or if `select lower(range) as "from"` is sufficient. You can make a generated column with `"from" numeric generated always as (lower(range)) stored` or you can make a view `create view as select lower(range) as "from"`. Note that `from` and `to` are SQL keywords and poor choices for column names. Consider something more descriptive of what the range actually is.